# VBA Global variables no longer declared after deleting worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have some public worksheet variables that are first initialized when the workbook is open.  I have a button that does this essentially:

```
Dim Response As Variant

Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this worksheet?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirm Action")
If Response = vbNo Then
    GoTo exit sub
End If

'Save workbook prior to deletion as a precaution
ThisWorkbook.Save

ActiveSheet.Delete
```

For some reason after this runs, those worksheet variables are no longer declared and I have to reinitialize them every time.  I tried adding my InitVariables macro call after the .Delete and it still doesn't work.

Any reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 10):

The reason is actually really simple - a Worksheet is a class in VBA, and its code module gets compiled along with the rest of your project *even if it's empty*.  When you delete a worksheet and let code execution stop, the next time you run some code the VBE has to recompile the project because you removed a code module.  That causes your custom class extensions to lose their state.

Note that this does *not* happen unless the code stops running and is recompiled.  This works just fine:

```
Sheet1.foo = 42        'foo is a public variable in Sheet1
Sheet2.Delete
Debug.Print Sheet1.foo 'Prints 42
```

Comment: I see.  Is there some way I can insert my InitVariables call during the recompile process then?

Comment: There's not really a good way to intercept the compile call, and certainly not from VBA.  What do you have in your globals?  If you can recreate them with an `InitVariables` call, wouldn't it be simpler to just call that before your code runs?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm doing.  I just didn't want to have to remember that every time I write a new sub or function.

Comment: I just tested it and the standard module loses it's value but a worksheet module public variable holds it's value.  I'm guessing that the standard modules get recompiled and not the worksheet modules?

Comment: @ThomasInzina - Interesting.  I imaging that the compiler is testing which objects need to be recompiled - it's possible in my case it had something to do with the litter of copy/pasted SO code that I had in the workbook.

Comment: Lol..it does build up

Answer (score 4):

I just tested it using Comintern foo.  It's interesting that the standard module foo losses it value but the public foo variable in a worksheet module does not loses it's value.

[image]