# Excel VBA - How to create a TRUE global variable

Tags: excel, vba

### What I want to do:

I want to know how to create a `TRUE` Global variable

### What I've found so far:

I have read hundreds of articles on creating a global variable in Excel, unfortunately, none of them really address the real question.

All of the examples I have seen work fine for a single worksheet, or just at the workbook level, but none are truly "GLOBAL" in that the variable can not be accessed/changed from any worksheet/VBA within the project/solution.

**To make this question explicit, I want to create a variable that can be:**

1. Set to a default value by the `Open_Workbook` procedure in the "workbook" space and
2. Accessed/changed from VBA procedures associated with ANY worksheet of the current workbook.

Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but this s a major issue that nobody seems to be able to answer concisely.

Comment: If you declare "Public MyGlobal As {TypeHere}" in a regular module (outside of any method) then that variable is accessible and settable from any module in the workbook.  If you're having problems, please post the actual code you used and describe the exact problem you're seeing.

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams. There's something you didn't tell us. Putting Public variable into standard module will do the trick. If you wanna retain the value after closing, you can consider creating hidden named range (well, without interacting with range), but you need to set it to default, so this is not, obviously, the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend `ThisWorkbook` with a custom property of instead of using a global variable:

```
'ThisWorkbook
Option Explicit

Private stored As Long

Public Property Get StoredValue() As Long
    StoredValue = stored
End Property

Public Property Let StoredValue(rhs As Long)
    stored = rhs
End Property

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    stored = 42
End Sub
```

This will hold its state for as long as the Workbook is open, with one important caveat - anything that forces the Workbook class to be recompiled will reset its state.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671309/vba-global-variables-no-longer-declared-after-deleting-worksheet/39671425#39671425) for more information. Note that there are work-arounds for this such as using a [custom property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.CustomProperties) instead of a private variable for a backing field.  Usage would be just like any other property of the Workbook, although you do need to refer to it by its code name:

```
'This code goes anywhere you want...
Public Sub Example()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.StoredValue
    ThisWorkbook.StoredValue = ThisWorkbook.StoredValue + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031210/excel-vba-how-to-create-a-true-global-variable#comment91020248_52031210) for about retaining values

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies to this, much appreciated.  The reply regarding the custom properties is exactly what I need.